# Difficulty with selecting certificate in google chrome

Tags: macos, google-chrome

this is my first question, so if I'm doing anything wrong just tell me.

Going to the subject...

I have an annoying problem with google chrome on my mac (MacOS High Sierra, MacBook Pro (13-inch)), chrome constantly updated in background, current release Version 74.0.3729.157 (Official Build) (64-bit)

When I restart google and want to go to some page which requires me to select an certificate from the list 4 of 5 times the list of certificates is somehow disabled , and I cannot select any of shown certificates.

So basically the list ist shown, but any attempts of clicking on any shown certificates is useles, nothing happens.

But as I said before, it works this way only 4 of 5 times, when I have my luck, the list is selectable and everithing works fine.

There is no difference in GUI where list is selectable or not, the only way of getting knowledge if everything is ok or not is to try to select one of certificates, sometimes I can select appropriate certificate and click ok, sometimes I cannot.

Have you got any clues what do I have to do to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem too. I found a solution that seems to work reliably just now.

When you get the problem, click anywhere in the address bar to place the focus there, then press Enter. The page will reload, and you will be able to select the certificate.

At last ! A solution :)

Answer (score -1):

there is a simple solutioon is to reload a page. Just grab a webpage name, press enter and after refreshing the page the certificate should be selectable